# Access a HttpSession in a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

I access my sessions in Spring MVC controllers simply with `@Autowired` like this:

```
@Autowired
private HttpSession session;
```

The problem is, I have now access the session within a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

I tried it with `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` but the result is (sometimes - and this is a real problem) `null`. I tried it also with `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` but than the `IllegalStateException` is thrown with the following message:

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

The `RequestContextListener` is registered in `web.xml`.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The same problem when I inject the session in the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` directly.

```
@Autowired
private HttpSession session;
```

My question is: how can I access the current `HttpSession` in the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your ClientHttpRequestInterceptor complete class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `HttpSession` by using the following in your `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`:

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request,
                                            byte[] body,
                                            ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
            // get the current session without creating a new one
            HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
            // get whatever session parameter you want
            String sessionParam = httpSession.getAttribute("parameter")
                                             .toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the usage of this `ClientHttpInterceptor` class is not in the right place, because as what I see in their [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)

> Intercepts client-side HTTP requests. Implementations of this interface can be registered with the RestTemplate

means that you can use this interceptor if your server behaves likes a client and for example you want to modify every request you send with `RestTemplate`. Sample usage for `ClientHttpInterceptor` [here](http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate).

You should use `HandlerInterceptor` . See good article [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/).

Comment: Yes, my server is also a client of a REST-API. I need to modify every request, by adding some credential headers to it. Some header needs information from the session for example a special user token.

Comment: Sure, the `preHandle` method of the `HandlerInterceptor` has the `HttpServletRequest` from I can get the session. The problem is, I need to intercept every `RestTemplate` request with it.

Comment: just extract the needed auth header from the `HandlerInterceptor`, pass it to the `ClientHttpInterceptor` and register your RestTemplate with your `ClientHttpInterceptor`.

Comment: How can I pass data from one interceptor to another?

Comment: think about the interceptors like `classes` because they are classes. So your question is "how to pass data from one class to other". See here http://mph-web.de/01_10_2013_resttemplate_basic_auth

Comment: Yes, sure, but if i try to get the session from a not managed bean I get the exceptions described above. Is there really no way in Spring to inject a `HttpSession` in an interceptor?